# Can I re-freeze shrimp?

Tags: freezing, shrimp

There’s a Phillipino grocery in our neighborhood that specializes in seafood. They sometimes have beautiful heads-on shrimp. I’ve no doubt that they’ve been frozen, then thawed, as we’re in the middle of a landlocked desert. It’s hard to resist them, though, as they’re only $6.99 a pound, compared with $9.99 a pound for frozen shrimp at the supermarket. And they’re heads-on!

Can frozen, then thawed shrimp be re-frozen? I’d sure love to scoop a couple of pounds and keep it in the freezer, for when I’m really craving shrimp (which is always).

Comment: Also freezing seafood is probably not like putting the seafood in your home freezer. Commercial processes would no doubt use flash freezing to freeze foods quickly which reduces the size of ice crystals so that the ice crystals don't rupture cell walls in the food.

Comment: Related, if not a full duplicate: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/.

Answer (score 4):

For safety reasons, it's strongly discouraged to re-freeze thawed products without cooking them first, as you don't know how long they have been waiting to be sold. Repeated freezing won't do anything nice to the texture, either.

But as you want to get a decent amount, can't you discuss with the grocer to buy them still frozen? If you then transport them in an icebox with cold elements, you should be able to get them in your home freezer safely.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of buying the shrimp frozen. I do that all the time, for exactly the reason brought up here.